# Can cache admission strategy be useful to prune distributed cache writes

Tags: caching, architecture, distributed-caching

Assume some distributed CRUD Service that uses a distributed cache that is not read-through (just some Key-Value store agnostic of DB). So there are n server nodes connected to m cache nodes (round-robin as routing). The cache is supposed to cache data stored in a DB layer.

So the default retrieval sequence seems to be:

- check if data is in cache, if so return data
- else fetch from DB
- **send data to cache** (cache does eviction)
- return data

The question is whether the individual service nodes can be smarter about what data to send to the cache, to reduce cache capacity costs (achieve similar hit ratio with less required cache storage space).
Given recent benchmarks on optimal eviction/admission strategies ([in particular LFU](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Efficiency)), some new caches might not even store data if it is deemed too infrequently used, maybe application nodes can do some best-effort guess.

So my idea is that the individual service nodes could evaluate whether data that was fetched from a DB should be send to the distributed cache or not based on an algorithm like LFU, thus reducing the network traffic between service and cache. I am thinking about local checks (suffering a lack of effectivity on cold startups), but checks against a shared list of cached keys may also be considered.

So the sequence would be

- check if data is in cache, if so return data
- else fetch from DB
- check if data key is frequently used

  - if yes, send data to cache (cache does eviction). Else not.
- return data

Is this possible, reasonable, has it already been done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common in databases, search, and analytical products to guard their LRU caches with filters to avoid pollution caused by scans. For example see Postgres' [Buffer Ring Replacement Strategy](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/storage/buffer/README#L208) and ElasticSearch's [filter cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/filter-caching.html#_autocaching_behavior). These are admission policies detached from the cache itself, which could be replaced if their caching algorithm was more intelligent. It sounds like your idea is similar, except a distributed version.

Most remote / distributed caches use classic eviction policies (LRU, LFU). That is okay because they are often excessively large, e.g. Twitter requires a [99.9% hit rate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxMKnx__uso) for their SLA targets. This means they likely won't drop recent items because the penalty is too high and oversize so that the victim is ancient.

However, that [breaks down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLRztKYvMLk) when batch jobs run and pollute the remote caching tier. In those cases, its not uncommon to see the cache population disabled to avoid impacting user requests. This is then a distributed variant of Postgres' problem described above.

The largest drawback with your idea is checking the item's popularity. This might be local only, which has a frequent cold start problem, or remote call which adds a network hop. That remote call would be cheaper than the traffic of shipping the item, but you are unlikely to be bandwidth limited. Likely you're goal would be to reduce capacity costs by a higher hit rate, but if your SLA requires a nearly perfect hit rate then you'll over provision anyway. It all depends on whether the gains by reducing cache-aside population operations are worth the implementation effort. I suspect that for most it hasn't been.

Comment: I was thinking local check only. Occasional cold starts would reduce the effectiveness, but not make it worse than not having a local admission policy I think. Very frequent cold starts would make it useless. You are right that the motivation is capacity cost reduction. Implementing admission policy based on shared data feels wrong to me, but good to mention the possibility.

Comment: @tkruse The closest published metrics might be from [Allegro's](https://allegro.tech/2017/01/estimating-the-cache-efficiency-using-big-data.html) usage of local caching to reduce their load on Cassandra. Obviously that is a completely different strategy, but showed a 27% reduction in system load. That setup is more common and has its own complexity, but nicely shows a reduction of capacity costs.